# how to update an object using mongoose, when some of the objects in the table haven't the specific searching id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a table of interactions like this.

```
   var interactions = new Schema({
   call_Id: {
       type: String,
       index: true
   },
   contact_id: {
       type: String,
       index: true
   },
   msgId: {
      type: String,
      default: null
   },
   interactions: []
 }, {
     timestamps: true,
     strict: false
 })

 module.exports = mongoose.model('interactions', interactions);




 var interactions = require('mongoose').model('interactions');


 exports.updateStatusOfMsg = (req, res) => {


let  id=req.body.messageId;

      interactions.findOneAndUpdate({'msgId': id }, {$set: 
      {status:req.body.status}}, {new: true}, (err, doc) => {
          if (err) {
              console.log("this is error "+err);
          }

        console.log("this is doc "+doc);
    });
     }
```

the problem is that, all the objects in the interactions tables have not the "msgId" property. is that possible that only those objects are search for updation whose has a property "msgId"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Model.findOneAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) will only update a document if found.
In the case of your program, you don't have to worry about documents that do not have the `msgId` attribute, they will not be found.